# Getting Data From ASP.NET MVC Membership Provider With AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, authentication

So I am using the built in ASP.NET MVC membership provider for the authorization of users in my web application.  I added several fields such as first name, last name and customer number to the default fields that it comes with (email, password).  I am able to register and log in users but now I want to get some of the information of the added fields for the user and use it in my AngularJS controller.

I have been working with learning AngularJS and have been successful with using the WebAPI to get and post data to the server but I am stumped on how I can get the information of the current user who is signed in to my application.  I am assuming it is stored in a session token of some sort but I do not know how to access it and work with that information from an angular standpoint.

Any help is appreciated, I can provide whatever code is necessary but at this point I only have the basic built in code that asp.net uses to register and login users and my empty angular controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get the current user from anywhere on the server side, use

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```